# How can I separate sequential decimal values from an optional sub pattern match in different capture groups?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input text:

`22 JUNPaypal *XPTO USD 11,99Conversão: USD 1 = R$ 5,5666,67`

And with this regex:

`(\d{2}\s{1}(?:JAN|FEV|MAR|ABR|MAI|JUN|JUL|AGO|SET|OUT|NOV|DEZ))(.*?)(?<!(?:USD|BRL|R\$)\s.?)((?:\d+\.)*?\d+,\d{2})`

I can generate the following 3 capture groups (separated by pipe to exemplify):

`22 JUN|Paypal *XPTO USD 11,99Conversão: USD 1 = R$ 5,|5666,67`

But what I **really** wanted was the following 3 capture groups:

`22 JUN|Paypal *XPTO USD 11,99Conversão: USD 1 = R$ 5,56|66,67`

Here's a live demo using ECMAScript engine:
https://regex101.com/r/UBMtdH/1/

### Notes

- the whole string is composed of several sequences like the one above
- the "USD 11,99Conversão: USD 1 = R$ 5,56" is optional, so it might not happen (hence the ?<!)
- values could have thousand separators (e.g.: 1.234,56)
- values will always have 2 decimal digits only
- using .NET regex engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match a least as possible after matching the month abbreviation, and use the [.net captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=netcore-3.1) property by matching the number with 2 decimals in a repeated capturing group.

At the end of the pattern, use a positive lookahead to assert either the end of the string, or another part that starts with 2 digits and the a month abbreviation.

```
(\d{2}\s(?:JAN|FEV|MAR|ABR|MAI|JUN|JUL|AGO|SET|OUT|NOV|DEZ))(.*?)(\d+,\d{2})+(?=$|\s*\d{2}\s(?:JAN|FEV|MAR|ABR|MAI|JUN|JUL|AGO|SET|OUT|NOV|DEZ))
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs%28%3f%3aJAN%7cFEV%7cMAR%7cABR%7cMAI%7cJUN%7cJUL%7cAGO%7cSET%7cOUT%7cNOV%7cDEZ%29%29%28.*%3f%29%28%5cd%2b%2c%5cd%7b2%7d%29%2b%28%3f%3d%24%7c%5cs*%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs%28%3f%3aJAN%7cFEV%7cMAR%7cABR%7cMAI%7cJUN%7cJUL%7cAGO%7cSET%7cOUT%7cNOV%7cDEZ%29%29&i=22+JUNPaypal+*XPTO+USD+11%2c99Convers%c3%a3o%3a+USD+1+%3d+R%24+5%2c5666%2c67+++++++++22+JUN+++++IOF+de+%22Paypal+*XPTO%224%2c2526+JUNFooBar+FooBar*Mi+29%2c0029+JUNPagamento+em+29+JUN+663%2c4401+JULPaypal+*IsPoof+USD+12%2c95Convers%c3%a3o%3a+USD+1+%3d+R%24+5%2c6673%2c29+++++++++01+JUL+++++IOF+de+%22Paypal+*IsPoof%224%2c6802+JULPaypal+*BarFoo+BRL+22%2c99+%3d+USD+4%2c24Convers%c3%a3o%3a+BRL+5%2c42+%3d+USD+1+%3d+R%24+5%2c7024%2c15+++++++++02+JUL+++++IOF+de+%22Paypal+*BarFoo%221%2c5404+JULPaypal+*Socio+30%2c0011+JULApple.Com%2fBi+10%2c9013+JULPaypal+*BarFoo+BRL+22%2c99+%3d+USD+4%2c30Convers%c3%a3o%3a+BRL+5%2c35+%3d+USD+1+%3d+R%24+5%2c5623%2c90+++++++++13+JUL+++++IOF+de+%22Paypal+*BarFoo%221%2c5214+JULPaypal+*Digital+A+35%2c0018+JULPaypal+*XPTO+USD+11%2c99Convers%c3%a3o%3a+USD+1+%3d+R%24+5%2c5766%2c79+++++++++18+JUL+++++IOF+de+%22Paypal+*XPTO%224%2c26)

[image]

Comment: This is a way to solve the problem and programatically I could use the decimals as I wanted.
Still, the best scenario for me would be to capture those 3rd group first decimals as part of the 2nd group. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: @YuriEastwood Do you mean like this with an optional third group? https://regex101.com/r/vxhFgU/1

Comment: No, I mean the last decimal will always be a part of the third group. But the previous optional decimal, when existent, will always be a part of the second group.

Comment: @YuriEastwood Can you give an example what should be in the second and what should be in the third group?

Comment: Was doing that, sorry! Following that first scenario:
22 JUN(1st)|Paypal *XPTO USD 11,99Conversão: USD 1 = R$ 5,56(2nd)|66,67(3rd)

Comment: @YuriEastwood So the other way around then? https://regex101.com/r/vhJ6CJ/1

Comment: Yes, that seems perfect! Thanks!
There are some texts in the end of the string that makes the last entry no being detected but I can strip it before applying the regex.